# Javascript Array object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am getting the following array from an interface and now I would like to get the value from the particular tag for a particular menu. How can I solve this best with javascript?

```
[
{
"title": "11-07 - 11-08",
"weekhit": "Weekhit from 11-07-08",
"days": {
"Monday, 2022-11-07": {
"Lunchmenue": "Lunchmenue from Monday 11-07",
"Vegimenue": "Vegimenue from Monday 11-07"
},
"Tuesday, 2022-11-08": {
"Lunchmenue": "Lunchmenue from Tuesday 11-08",
"Vegimenue": "Vegimenue from Tuesday 11-08"
}
}
},
{
"title": "11-14 - 11-15",
"weekhit": "Weekhit from 11-14-15",
"days": {
"Monday, 12022-11-14": {
"Lunchmenue": "Lunchmenue from Monday 11-14",
"Vegimenue": "Vegimenue from Monday 11-14"
},
"Tuesday, 2022-11-15": {
"Lunchmenue": "Lunchmenue from Tuesday 11-15",
"Vegimenue": "Vegimenue from Tuesday 11-15"
}
}
}
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest reading [mcve] as it will assist you in getting the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use map() fun to get the value

Comment: Please include an actual example if you are going to be adding an answer